# Cakephp relationship issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

```
Company class
  public $hasMany = array(
    'Person' => array(
        'className' => 'Lasso.Person',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',

    )



Person class
public $belongsTo = array(
                'Company' => array(
        'className' => 'Lasso.Company',
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => 'company',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

How do I get my company_id field within my People views to be the display name of Company rather than just the value of company_id?

Answer (score 0):

```
public $displayField = 'companyName';
```

Comment: I figured it out!  Needed to do this in my view:
     $people = $this->Company->Person->find('list');
     $this->set(compact('people'));

Comment: @JustinYoung You did what in your view?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Person` class you can write that:

```
public $belongTo = array(
    'Company' => array(
          'className' => 'Lesso.Company',
          'foreignKey' => 'company_id', // Here use company_id instead of id
          .....
     )
);
```

and also you need to put `company_id` field in `persons` table.